# "sudo matlab" logs in as demo version

Tags: 14.04, sudo, matlab, license

I was using a demo version of MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04 for the last month, before purchasing a license today. The licensing procedure required me to download a file, "license.lic" and then point the program towards this in **Resources -> Help -> Licensing -> Activate**

Now when I run "matlab" from the terminal, it opens a registered version of the product.  But when I run `sudo matlab` (which I need to do) it opens the original trial version.

I have also asked Matlab support, but thought someone on here might be able to help me.

Very appreciative of any help!
Don.

Comment: Why do you have to run `matlab` as root?

Answer (score 1):

You should try

`$ sudo -E matlab`

This will tell sudo to preserve your environment variables.  If this doesn't work, Matlab is probably loading a configuration file from `/root` instead of `/home/username`.  You can check where the configuration is located using the `prefdir` command in Matlab.  I believe it is located under `/home/username/.matlab`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. So in /home/username/.matlab, there is a file called R2016a_licenses which I'm guessing I'll need to copy into the root?

Comment: Should have added, $ sudo -E matlab does not work :(